# Time-complexity and alternatives for an algorithm with a loop in a recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, time-complexity

I am now thinking about it and hope that I will get some help here.
My problem looks like this:

```
to_delete = [a,[b[c,x]]d[e[[f]]]]
to_stay   = [a,[b[c,d]],[e,f[[]]]]
```

I have distributed elements on various layers and try to remove elements in to_delete that are not in to_stay. These must be on the same level.
In the example I would remove "x" and "f".

Since the order is important, I've solved it using lists with a recursive loop, so that the layers are traversed and further sublists are searched for, starting at the deletion at the lowest level and then deleting on the previous levels recursively.
Like:

```
level_above(list)
  for element in list:
     if element is list:
        level_above(element)
     else: 
        compare element with to_stay(same level) and if no match in order, delete
        return element
```

It worked, but I'd like to get your assessment on time complexity.

From similar questions I would guess this algorithm has a complexity of O (2^n)?
Even though 20 levels and 50 elements were traversed, it was fast.
That's why I'm a little confused.

Are there alternatives in terms of performance, other data structures?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just as a note, Big-O just indicates how a function grows when approaching infinity. There are many examples where algorithms with a worse complexity class actually are much faster for practical inputs. For example, due to a small constant factor. Something like `2^n` can be small for small inputs and thus fast. But if you input large stuff, it gets worse.

Comment: Thank you. Could this algorithm perform faster with another data structure?